# making a dropdown menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a dropdown menu for "My Journeys" in the navigation bar using javascript, and I am using flex for the css. And I have no idea what to do, all of the tutorials I've watched didn't use flex for the code. Thank you for your help!

This is my html body code

```
<body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="pagewrap">
    <header>
        <img alt= "header" src = "pict/header.jpg">
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="html.html"> Home </a> </li>
            <div id="dropdown">
                <li> <a href= "Journey.html">My Journeys</a></li>
            </div>
            <li> <a href="Media.html"> Media </a></li>
            <li> <a href="About.html"> About Me &amp; This Blog </a></li>
        </ul>


        <form>
            <input type="search" placeholder="search...">
            <input type="image" src="pict/search-white.png" alt="search"> 
        </form>
    </nav>


</div>
</body>
```

and this is my css code

```
.pagewrap{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: blue;
width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;

background-color: black;
}

body{
background-image: url(pict/wallpaper.jpeg);
}

header img{
width: 100%;
margin-top: 4%;
}

nav{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
order: -1;

height: 8%;
width: 75%;
top: 0;

background-color: black;
opacity: 0.9;

align-items: center;
position: fixed;
}

nav ul{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
}

nav ul li, #dropdown{
list-style: none;
flex-grow: 1;

margin: 0 2%;
}

nav ul li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;

font-family: 'Candal', sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
color: #660066;
}

form{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
justify-content: flex-start;


width: 20%;
height: 50%;
}

form input[type="search"]{
border-width: 0;
color: white;
background-color: transparent;

}

form input[type="image"]{
margin: auto 2%;
width: 5%;
}
```

Comment: you should not use div inside ul

Comment: @kalista lanti, what are you actually planning to achieve?

Comment: Opening your code I got this: http://i.imgur.com/yy8BLmW.png . What you want in the dropdown? Do you want like here http://codepen.io/lawnch/pen/Jbpng ?

Comment: I wan't the drop down at the my journeys navigation part with only 2 submenus in it. as simple as that actually. @imGaurav thanks, but then if I delete it, what should I do next? :)

Answer (score 0):

what i have made up from your question is you need my journey drop down with two submenus. Below is the code for same.
Hope it will help.

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function(){ $('.myList').slideToggle(100);});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.pagewrap {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    background-image: url(pict/wallpaper.jpeg);
}
header img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    padding:5px;
}
nav ul {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li, #dropdown {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'Candal', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #F99D9D;
}
form {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
}
form input[type="search"] {
    border-width: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
form input[type="image"] {
    margin: auto 2%;
    width: 5%;
}
.myList {
    position:absolute;
    top:24px;
    left:0;
    background:#A0A0A0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:1
}
.myList li {
    margin:0;
}
.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagewrap">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">My Journeys</a> 
                <ul class="myList" style="display:none;">
                    <li> <a href="#">menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Media </a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> About Me &amp; This Blog </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```